# Is the weakening of O-H bond due to -I effect of sugar groups?

Tags: chemical-biology

In DNA molecule after formation of phosphodiester bond with two nucleosides the O-H bond of phosphate group becomes highly weak and the H+ is lost. This makes the DNA acidic but what causes the weakening of O-H bond? Is it due to the -I effect of sugar groups?

[image]

Comment: ? Free phosphoric acid dissociates anyway... you don't need a sugar there to make it dissociate

Comment: The PO42- group is not due to phosphoric acid. It is derived from dNTP/NTP.

Comment: which is in turn derived from phosphoric acid